# Which mail daemon does OS X 10.8.4 run by default?

Tags: macos, terminal, email, webserver

I'm debugging some mail related stuff on my Mac, and not quite sure how my system is even sending mail.

I can run a simple command like `date | mail -s test myemail@mydomain.com` and receive an email just fine. Cool. I can also use PHP's `mail()` function to send mail. PHP's `sendmail_path` configuration variable is `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`, looks okay.

But the weird thing is I don't think Postfix is even running...

```
$ postqueue -p
postqueue: fatal: Queue report unavailable - mail system is down
$ ps -aef | grep -i postfix
  501 28403 25525   0  2:10PM ttys042    0:00.00 grep -i postfix
$ launchctl list | grep -i mail
-   0   com.apple.MailMigratorService
70829   -   0x7fa87941a060.anonymous.Mail
$ launchctl list | grep -i postfix
-   0   org.postfix.master
```

How is my Mac even sending mail from the `mail` terminal command if Postfix isn't running? Is there some other mail daemon OS X runs?

Comment: I don't know the details, but Postfix spawns when you use the `mail` command, and shuts down shortly afterward.  Try `mail`ing something and note you can reach Postfix on port 25 for a bit afterward, but not later.

Comment: Postfix is the default! It comes pre installed with osx.

Comment: Try disabling it  with sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist

Answer (score 6):

It is using postfix. At a high-level, when you execute the `mail` command, the following is happening:

- Invoking `mail` drops your message as a file in the postfix maildrop directory, i.e.,  `/var/spool/postfix/maildrop`. This happens because `mail` calls `sendmail` which calls `postdrop` which puts the file in the maildrop.
- The postfix main daemon, `master` is configured to startup when the maildrop has files in it. This is specified in the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist` file.
- The `master` daemon starts other needed postfix processes such as `pickup`, `qmgr` and `smtp` to deliver the mail.
- All these process including the master daemon die after being idle for period of time.

The `postqueue -p` command needs the showq daemon which will be started  only when master is running. When that's not the case, you see that error. The `showq` daemon can be configured to always be running so that you can use the `postqueue -p` command. If you want to just see the mail queue, you can do this:

```
$ sudo postfix start && postqueue -p && sudo postfix stop
```

But note that if you start it this way, you must shut it down too. Otherwise the postfix master daemon will be resident and won't be on-demand anymore.

If you want to know which processes start after you issue `mail`, you can use the `execsnoop` command to see which process are starting up:

```
$ sudo execsnoop -v
STRTIME                UID    PID   PPID ARGS
2016 Apr 20 23:57:52   501   2358   1154 mail
2016 Apr 20 23:57:52   501   2359   2357 date
2016 Apr 20 23:57:52   501   2360      1 sendmail
2016 Apr 20 23:57:52   501   2367   2360 postdrop
2016 Apr 20 23:57:52     0   2369   2343 cleanup
2016 Apr 20 23:58:23     0   2384      1 master
2016 Apr 20 23:58:23     0   2385   2384 pickup
2016 Apr 20 23:58:23     0   2386   2384 qmgr
2016 Apr 20 23:58:24     0   2387   2384 bounce
2016 Apr 20 23:58:24     0   2388   2384 trivial-rewrite
2016 Apr 20 23:58:24     0   2389   2384 local
2016 Apr 20 23:58:24     0   2390   2384 smtp
```